# childBrowser on PhoneGap only shows in portrait

Tags: ios, html, cordova

I'm using childbrowser for iOS 5.0, XCODE 4.2, phonegap 1.1.0 and I'm only able to pull it up in portrait mode. My app supports all 4 views but when I select a, I get the browser in portrait mode only. I do get this error message:

The view controller  returned NO from -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: for all interface orientations. It should support at least one orientation.

But i know very little xcode - so I'm not able to fix this :(

help

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, if you look in ChildBrowserViewController there is a function called shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.

The first couple of lines look at the configuration of supported orientations, but it will only rotate if you have more than one orientation setup.  I only had landscape right setup so it didn't do it.

If you set the autoRotate to YES or comment out the if block, it will check that the current orientation is supported, and if it is it will rotate to it.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation 
{
    //BOOL autoRotate = [self.supportedOrientations count] > 1; // autorotate if only more than 1 orientation supported
    //if (autoRotate)
    //{
        if ([self.supportedOrientations containsObject:
             [NSNumber numberWithInt:interfaceOrientation]]) {
            return YES;
        }
    //}

    return NO;
}
```